# How do I add a delay to this when hovering over for height change?

Tags: hover, jquery-animate, delay

```
$(function(){
    $("#top-img").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:"400px"},{queue:false,duration:700});
        }, 

        function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({height:"300px"},{queue:false,duration:700});
    });
});
```

This is the code I am using, its simple for the most part. When I hover over the div `#top-img` it takes it from a height (set in CSS) of `300px` and animates it to a height of `400px`.

I would like a slight delay so that

1. people have to hover over it for a second before it runs and
2. you have to move off of it for a second before it goes back to
   `300px`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery plugin. I;ve used it in the past and its extremely easy to use and implement

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works, but the problem is when hovering and off hovering a lot of times it does not end and just keep going up and down.  So I need to some how add what I need out of both. .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top-img").hover(function(){
    $(this).delay(400).animate({height:400},1000);
},function(){

    $(this).delay(300).animate({height:300},500);
    });
});
```